# How do I show a loading screen while running an API query in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, google-places-api

I'me trying to figure out how to show a loading screen while running an API query and saving the data. This is in SWIFT and I'm using Alamofire. My latest attempt involves adding a completion handler to the API search method...

```
func search(keyword: String, location: String, radius: String, completion: () -> ()) {

    urlString = self.baseURL + self.KEY + location + radius + keyword

    AlamoManager.request(.GET, urlString).responseJSON { response in

        if let newJSON = response.result.value, let results = newJSON["results"] {
            let newPlaces = results!.valueForKey("name") as! [AnyObject]

            for newPlace in newPlaces {
                self.cd.saveData(newPlace as! String)
            }

            print("\nSAVED 1ST BATCH...\n")

            if let token = newJSON["next_page_token"] as? String {
                let nextPageURL = self.baseURL + self.KEY + "&pagetoken=\(token as! String)"
                sleep(3)

                self.AlamoManager.request(.GET, nextPageURL).responseJSON { response in
                    if let newJSON2 = response.result.value , let results = newJSON2["results"] {
                        let newPlaces2 = results!.valueForKey("name") as! [AnyObject]

                        for newPlace in newPlaces2 {
                            self.cd.saveData(newPlace as! String)
                        }
                        print("\nSAVED 2ND BATCH...\n")

                        if let token = newJSON2["next_page_token"] as? String {
                            let lastPageURL = self.baseURL + self.KEY + "&pagetoken=\(token as! String)"
                            sleep(3)

                            self.AlamoManager.request(.GET, lastPageURL).responseJSON { response in
                                if let newJSON2 = response.result.value, let results = newJSON2["results"] {

                                    var newPlaces3 = results?.valueForKey("name") as! [AnyObject]

                                    for newPlace in newPlaces3 {
                                        self.cd.saveData(newPlace as! String)
                                    }
                                    print("\nSAVED 3RD BATCH...\n")
                                } else {
                                    print("Didn't get the 3rd JSON.")
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("NO MORE PAGES AVAILABLE")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Didn't get the second json")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        completion()
    }
}
```

... then calling the loading animation in viewDidLoad and stopping it in the completion call....

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.loadingOverlayView.showLoadingOverlay(self.view)

    self.gp.search(self.keyword, location: location, radiusInput: "5000", completion: { () -> () in
        self.loadingOverlayView.hideLoadingOverlay(self.view)
    })

}
```

The problem is the loading screen is removed before the query ends. How do I make it so it only stops once the query is finished? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `completion()` call should be where you print `"\nSAVED 3RD BATCH...\n"`

```
func search(keyword: String, location: String, radius: String, completion: () -> ()) {

    urlString = self.baseURL + self.KEY + location + radius + keyword

    AlamoManager.request(.GET, urlString).responseJSON { response in

        if let newJSON = response.result.value, let results = newJSON["results"] {
            let newPlaces = results!.valueForKey("name") as! [AnyObject]

            for newPlace in newPlaces {
                self.cd.saveData(newPlace as! String)
            }

            print("\nSAVED 1ST BATCH...\n")

            if let token = newJSON["next_page_token"] as? String {
                let nextPageURL = self.baseURL + self.KEY + "&pagetoken=\(token as! String)"
                sleep(3)

                self.AlamoManager.request(.GET, nextPageURL).responseJSON { response in
                    if let newJSON2 = response.result.value , let results = newJSON2["results"] {
                        let newPlaces2 = results!.valueForKey("name") as! [AnyObject]

                        for newPlace in newPlaces2 {
                            self.cd.saveData(newPlace as! String)
                        }
                        print("\nSAVED 2ND BATCH...\n")

                        if let token = newJSON2["next_page_token"] as? String {
                            let lastPageURL = self.baseURL + self.KEY + "&pagetoken=\(token as! String)"
                            sleep(3)

                            self.AlamoManager.request(.GET, lastPageURL).responseJSON { response in
                                if let newJSON2 = response.result.value, let results = newJSON2["results"] {

                                    var newPlaces3 = results?.valueForKey("name") as! [AnyObject]

                                    for newPlace in newPlaces3 {
                                        self.cd.saveData(newPlace as! String)
                                    }
                                    print("\nSAVED 3RD BATCH...\n")
                                    completion() /// <------ HERE
                                } else {
                                    print("Didn't get the 3rd JSON.")
                                    completion() /// <------ HERE
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("NO MORE PAGES AVAILABLE")
                            completion() /// <------ HERE
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Didn't get the second json")
                        completion() /// <------ HERE
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            completion() /// <------ HERE
        }

    }
}
```

Also why are you adding `sleep(3)`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Stijn. The data request can run 2 more times depending on the results of the last query. That's why there are nested if-statements. The sleep(3) is the 3 second pause required by Google Places to run additional calls.

Comment: Oke then also add an completion call on an `else`, I edited my post to reflect what I mean. Also if this is running on the main thread I would not suggest using `sleep`, because it blocks the thread, you can better use a [timer](https://gist.github.com/natecook1000/b0285b518576b22c4dc8)

Comment: `I would not suggest using sleep` Very true. But do not use a timer either. Use callbacks or NSOperations or any queuing process - but don't rely on *time* for these tasks.